# How can I load multiple images with Next Image from a loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have:

```
const TEMPLATE_TYPES = [
    {
        name: 'Blog Post',
        type: 'blog-post',
        img: '/img1.png'
    },...
];
```

Later, I have a loop over `TEMPLATE_TYPES`:

```
{templateType.img && <img src={templateType.img} />}
```

But I want to convert this to Next.js's `<Image />` tag. How would I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried replacing `img` with `Image`? (sorry if you have, but in that case you should've said so)

Comment: But they aren't imported images then

Comment: Ok, so do `img: require('./assets/img1.png')` or similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the nextJs docs:

> Next.js can serve static files, like images, under a folder called public in the root directory. Files inside public can then be referenced by your code starting from the base URL (/).

as long as your images are in the public folder you don't have to import them, so just keep as it is.

```
// TEMPLATE_TYPES
img: '/img1.png'
```

but keep in mind that:

> Note: Only assets that are in the public directory at build time will be served by Next.js. Files added at runtime won't be available. We recommend using a third party service like AWS S3 for persistent file storage.

See [the docs about serving static content](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving) for more info.

Another thing, in the future maybe you will want to access files from a remote domain, like aws bucket, in such case you have to add the domain on the `next.config.js` like so:

```
// next.config.js file
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['example.com', 'example2.com'],
  },
}
```

for more info [take a look here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#domains)

and finally, you can create a component that gets the object and render your images:

```
const RenderImage = (props) => {
  const images = props.images;
  return (
    <>
      {images.map((img, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          <h4>{img.name}</h4>
          <Image src={img.img} width={500} height={300} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

//Later somewhere on your code:
<RenderImage images={TEMPLATE_TYPES} />
```

The code above is just an example, but i think you got the idea, see also [the api docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image) about the image component. Hope i helped a bit!